# sql join which tells me if ID exists in other table

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables:

```
 A      B
 --    ----
 ID    FKID
 --    ----
 1      3
 2      3   
 3      4
 4      4
```

I need a select statement which shows me all of A with a field that tells me if table B has any ids that match that ID.

```
Desired Result
-----------
 ID | hasB
-----------
 1    no
 2    no    
 3    yes
 4    yes
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In SQL Server this would be the most efficient way rather than doing an `OUTER JOIN` then removing the duplicates with `DISTINCT`. Not sure for postgres, you'd need to check the plans.

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   B
                      WHERE  B.FKID = A.ID) THEN 'yes'
         ELSE 'no'
       END AS hasB
FROM   A
```

Comment: +1 : Agreed that this *is likely* to avoid unnecessary load on the server by avoiding the need for GROUP BY, DISTINCT and not needing to process all duplicate rows in tableB.

Comment: @Dems: You bring awesome "value added" to this community by helping a person make a decision. Your comments are greatly appreciated. (+1) to you both.

Comment: @capdragon : I can also be a pain in the butt, but I thank you all the same :)

Comment: @Dems Do you have anything to back up the claim that multiple selects are faster than using `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @KristianAntonsen I think Martin and Dems are correct... in my test against tables with about 100k rows, Martin's solution is 5 times faster than my solution.  The execution plans end up being very similar, except using a distinct or group by adds an additional distinct sort operation...

Comment: @KristianAntonsen - Even though the syntax looks like a correlated sub query it is in fact a semi join. It would only be implemented as multiple selects if it was a nested loop join. In SQL Server the query optimiser can also use the two other available join types (hash and merge) to satisfy this query.

Comment: Thank you so much .

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ID,
    CASE WHEN b.FKID IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END AS hasB
FROM
    tableA a LEFT JOIN
    tableB b ON a.ID = b.FKID
```

Comment: 1:many relationship will cause duplicates in the output.  (Use GROUP BY as well, or EXISTS instead?)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work out for you depending on what the DB platform actually is.  You may need to swap the case for an IIF on something lovely like MS Access.

```
select A.ID, case when B.FKID IS NULL then 'no' else 'yes' end as hasB from A left join B on A.ID = B.FKID
```

Comment: 1:many relationship will cause duplicates in the output.  (Use GROUP BY as well, or EXISTS instead?)   [@Oybek - the EXISTS form should be readable to any capable SQL user, and as this causes duplicate results, it's either incorrect, or incomplete.]

Comment: I'd say I'm incorrect for sure - perils of not reading the question fully before typing. I'd have gone with the EXISTS had I noted the one to many nature of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID, "no" as hasB from a where not(id in (select fkid from b) )

union

SELECT ID, "yes" as hasB from a where id in (select fkid from b)

Comment: Will scan both tables twice, can be formed without needing twice the scans.

Comment: In general, can be better than a join depending on the indices set up on the table and dimensions of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,IF(FKID,'yes','no') AS hasB
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.FKID;
```

You'll get

```
+------+------+
| ID   | hasB |
+------+------+
|    1 | no   |
|    2 | no   |
|    3 | yes  |
|    4 | yes  |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should do:
`select distinct a.id,(case when b.fkid is null then 0 else 1 end) as hasb from tablea a 
left join tableb b on a.id=b.fkid`

`select a.id,(case when exists(select * from tableb where a.id=fkid) then 1 else 0 end) as hasb from tablea a`