# SQL Check if linked data exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create a query that checks which companies have already implemented data on certain levels i.e. other tables.

For now I have to check which companies have addresses linked to them.

The tables that I need are linked as follows:

- Company
- Establishment (linked with company through companyId)
- Address (linked with Establishment through establishmentId)

I have already created a query which checks if data for a company has been implemented on an establishment level, I have pasted this query below

```
SELECT c.id as 'Company Id', 
CASE e.companyId WHEN c.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'EstablishmentImplementation'
FROM company c LEFT JOIN establishment e ON c.Id = e.companyId
```

I have already tried the query pasted below, but the results I get from this aren't correct when I go check in the system.

```
SELECT c.id as 'Company Id', 
CASE a.establishmentID WHEN e.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'AdressesImplementation'
FROM company c JOIN establishment e ON c.Id = e.companyId
LEFT JOIN address a ON e.Id = a.establishmentId
```

How can I get a list of all companies with the correct indication on whether it has implemented data on an address level or not?

---

EDIT

---

I understand this question is very similar to this one: [sql join which tells me if ID exists in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418462/sql-join-which-tells-me-if-id-exists-in-other-table)

But in this case I don't have the necessary FK (companyId) available in the Address table.

If I transform the example from the other question to the format I'm using it would look more like this (where A = Company, B = Establishment, C = Address):

```
A      B           C
--    ---------   ----------
ID    ID | FKID    ID | FKID
--    ---|-----   ----|------
1      9 |  3      10 | 8
2      8 |  3      11 | 8
3      7 |  4      12 | 9
4      6 |  4      13 | 9
```

And the result would be this:

```
-----------------
 ID | hasB | hasC
-----------------
 1    no     no
 2    no     no
 3    yes    yes
 4    yes    no
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql join which tells me if ID exists in other table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418462/sql-join-which-tells-me-if-id-exists-in-other-table)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id as 'Company Id', 
CASE WHEN  a.establishmentID=e.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'AdressesImplementation'
FROM company c 
INNER JOIN establishment e ON c.Id = e.companyId
LEFT JOIN address a ON e.Id = a.establishmentId

OR

SELECT c.id as 'Company Id', 'EstablishmentImplementation'
FROM company c 
INNER JOIN establishment e ON c.Id = e.companyId
INNER JOIN address a ON e.Id = a.establishmentId
```

Try above code.
Here you missed with correct syntex of `CASE WHEN`.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I get the same result as before when I try your suggestion.